# Can't detect Windows App on Weinre?

Tags: windows, cordova, sencha-touch, weinre

I'm running Weinre on Mac. I have an HTML5-based Windows app installed on a Windows phone. If I try to access my app via the browser inside the Windows phone, I am able to detect the app on Weinre without any problems. However, if I open the actual installed Windows app (not via the browser), I can't see my app listed on Weinre. What could be the error and how do I fix it?

Note: I'm using Chrome as my debug client. The model of the phone I'm using is Nokia Lumia 925 (Windows Phone 8.1).

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

It may be a lot of work, but if you install Windows in a VM, you could use Visual Studio: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2014/07/21/how-to-remotely-debug-and-profile-the-performance-of-your-html5-websites-amp-apps-on-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Raymond, for your suggestion. I do have a VM with Visual Studio installed. However, it runs so slow that I won't dare use it. Do you know if it's possible to access an HTML5-based Windows app on weinre?

Comment: No. I checked the weinre home page and it definitely isn't listed a supported there.